# Pulling the Lat and Long from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have URL's that look like this:

```
var results['GoogleLink'] = http://maps.google.com/?q=33.6745%2C%20-117.167%20(%22Menifee+Valley+Farmers+Market%22)
```

From this, I want:

```
33.6745%2C%20-117.167%20
```

I tried this (crappy non-working trial)

```
var expression = '/\/?q=\/(.*)/[1]';
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var original = results['GoogleLink'];
```

How can I parse this string and return the part I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var results = "http://maps.google.com/?q=33.6745%2C%20-117.167%20(%22Menifee+Valley+Farmers+Market%22)" ;
results=results.substring(results.indexOf("=")+1, results.lastIndexOf("("));
alert(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
var expression = '/\/?q=\/(.*)/[1]';
var original = results['GoogleLink'];
var result = expression.test(original);
```

you can use *result* to validation